# How to Refactor LINQ Query to Use Delegate or Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda

This method works great and generates only 1 query (utilizing .Includes() to eager load).
However, I would like to refactor the AbleToDelete code to be more reusable.
(Using EF4)

```
        public override IEnumerable<AffectProjection> SelectAll(SearchAffects page)
        {
            IQueryable<Affect> query = BuildSearchQuery(page);

            IEnumerable<AffectProjection> results = query.Select(entity => new AffectProjection()
            {
                AffectID = entity.AffectID,
                AffectCode = entity.AffectCode,
                AffectName = entity.AffectName,

                AbleToDelete = !((entity.Foo1s.Any(pa => !pa.Inactive))
                                || (entity.Foo2s.Any(ea => !ea.Inactive))
                                || (entity.Foo3s.Any(sa => !sa.Inactive))
                                || (entity.Foo4s.Any(spa => !spa.Inactive)))
            }).ToArray();

            return results;
        }
```

I moved the code into an Expression Func structure but can't figure out how to replace my code that is setting the AbleToDelete property.  Advise?

```
public Expression<Func<Affect, bool>> DelegateExpression = entity =>
            !((entity.Foo1s.Any(pa => !pa.Inactive))
                || (entity.Foo2s.Any(ea => !ea.Inactive))
                || (entity.Foo3s.Any(sa => !sa.Inactive))
                || (entity.Foo4s.Any(spa => !spa.Inactive)));
```

Last but not least, this solution compiles but fails at runtime with error: "NotSupportedException - The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."  Trying to use a delegate which isn't supported:

```
        public override IEnumerable<AffectProjection> SelectAll(SearchAffects page)
        {
            IQueryable<Affect> query = BuildSearchQuery(page);

            //Create delegate instance and register method -- single statement
            var deleteAbilityAllowed = new CanDelete(GetAbleToDelete);

            IEnumerable<AffectProjection> results = query.Select(entity => new AffectProjection()
            {
                AffectID = entity.AffectID,
                AffectCode = entity.AffectCode,
                AffectName = entity.AffectName,

                AbleToDelete = deleteAbilityAllowed(entity)
            }).ToArray();

            return results;
        }

        public delegate bool CanDelete(Affect entity);

        public bool GetAbleToDelete(Affect entity)
        {
            return !((entity.Foo1s.Any(pa => !pa.Inactive))
                || (entity.Foo2s.Any(ea => !ea.Inactive))
                || (entity.Foo3s.Any(sa => !sa.Inactive))
                || (entity.Foo4s.Any(spa => !spa.Inactive)));
        }
```

Please advise and thank you in advance!

Comment: `? false : true` is equivalent to `!`.

Comment: I switched the code above per suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) contains methods that allow you to do this. With it, you can use yout `DelegateExpression`. To do that, add `AsExpandable()` to the source of your query and then invoke the Expression using `Invoke()`:

```
var expression = DelegateExpression;

var results = query.AsExpandable().Select(entity => new AffectProjection()
{
    AffectID = entity.AffectID,
    AffectCode = entity.AffectCode,
    AffectName = entity.AffectName,
    AbleToDelete = expression.Invoke(entity)
}).ToArray();
```

Be careful though, it seems you can't use the expression directly from the field, it has to be from a local variable.

Comment: I actually found that add-on but wasn't sure how to implement.  Makes sense and I'll give it a try - then mark as answer if works as expected.  Thanks!